# How to emit signal from Dialog to a slot in MainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt5

I've been trying to learn about signals and slots as it seems to be  the proper way to communicating between classes in PyQT.

Below you'll find my code, let me walk trough the code with you as you'll better understand my problem.

1. I have a mainwindow with a pushbutton
2. When the button is clicked, a dialog window is executed.
3. The User inputs some data in textLineEdits, then clicks on a "Add" button
4. The Data is dumped to a Json File

And here's where I come to a halt:

- When my data gets written in my Json file, I want to emit a signal with 2 strings as argument.
- Connect the signal with a function in MainWindow class in order to add Items to my Combobox (the ComboBox is in the MainWindow)

Here's my demonstration code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

import sys

import ui.mainwindow as MnWindow
import ui.AddUserDialog as AddUserDialog

class MainWindow(QMainWindow,MnWindow.Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButtonAddUser.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)

    def showDialog(self):
        d = AddUserDialog(self)
        d.exec_()

    #Catch the emited signal from AddUserDialog and connect it to AddToCombo function
    def AddToCombo(self,first,last):
        self.UserComboBox.addItem(first + ' ' + last)

class AddUserDialog(QDialog,AddUserDialog.Ui_Dialog):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(AddUserDialog,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButtonAddUser.clicked.connect(self.AddUser)

    def AddUser(self):
        new_user = {
        'firstname' : self.lineEditPrenom.text(),
        'lastname' : self.lineEditNom.text(),
        'Adresse' : self.lineEditAdresse.text(),
        'Town' : self.lineEditVille.text(),
        'ZipCode' : self.lineEditCodePostal.text(), 
        }

        with open('MyJsonFile.json','r') as f:
            data = json.load(f)

        data['users'].append(new_user)

        with open('MyJsonFile.json','w') as f:
            json.dump(data,f,indent=3)

        #Emit signal with new_user['firstname'] & new_user['lastname'] as arguments

        self.close()    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainWindow()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick

Hi Nick,
Thanks for your comment. this is a minimal version of my code, I started it from scratch and left only the parts that are relevant to my problem. Hope it's not exhaustive as I don't see how can I get it more minimalist.
regards,

Comment: @Hamouza please improve your indentation, in python is very important

Comment: you forgot to publish the modules `mainwindow.py` and `AddUserDialog.py`

Comment: I create my GUIs using Qt Designer, So I don't look that much into those two files as I just import them and never edit them. So are those files still relevant to the problem ?
Thanks,

Comment: @eyllanesc I will definitely take note of your comment. Can you point out for me where the indentation is messed up in my code please ? And Also if you have any help or ressources that might solve my problem, I'd be thankful for that.
Thanks,

Comment: @Hamouza see this lines: `self.pushButtonAddUser.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)` and `self.pushButtonAddUser.clicked.connect(self.AddUser)`

Comment: @Hamouza On the other hand, do not ask for resources since in SO it is off-topic besides being annoying, please avoid those comments.

Comment: @eyllanesc Indeed, those lines indentation are wrong, it was a copy/paste typo.

Don't know how my comment is annoying but whatever, sorry, just trying to get help here.

So, Do you please have any idea on how to solve this ?

Thanks,

Comment: @Hamouza Well then correct it, you have to take the time to show the best possible post avoiding typographical errors since they only distract.

Comment: @eyllanesc It should be all good now. Thanks.

Do you know how I can fix my problem please ?

Comment: @Hamouza Please avoid pointing to the same comment: *how I can fix my problem please*, because if I know the answer and want to answer then I will.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal you need to do three things: define a signal in `AddUserDialog()`, connect this signal to the appropriate slot in `MainWindow.showDialog()`, and emit this signal in `AddUserDialog.AddUser()`

With this in mind, `AddUserDialog` becomes something like

```
class AddUserDialog(QDialog):

    # define a signal that emits two strings
    user_added = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, str)

    ...

    def AddUser(self):
        ...

        # emit signal
        self.user_added.emit(new_user['firstname'], new_user['lastname'])
        self.close()
```

and `MainWindow`:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow,MnWindow.Ui_MainWindow):

    ....

    def showDialog(self):
        d = AddUserDialog(self)

        # connect signal to appropriate slot
        d.user_added.connect(self.AddToCombo)

        d.exec_()

    ....
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, It's very clear to me how the process of this works. Although, I did what you suggested to me.  
At first glance, I had this error: `AttributeError: 'AddUserDialog' object has no attribute 'user_added'
`   
I change user_added to self.user_added, and it gives me this error: `AttributeError: 'PyQt5.QtCore.pyqtSignal' object has no attribute 'connect'`   

I don't know what I'm messing up here.

Thanks again

Comment: It sounds like you didn’t define the signal correctly. The definition of `user_added` in `AddUserDialog` should be outside any methods (so for example after `class AddUserDialog(...):` and before `def __init__`)